# Ruby Action Mailer wont send to smtp in development

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I want to configure my development environment to send emails via Sendgrid as my app does in production.

I have set up the development configuration the same but when I use 'runner' with the development environment is always just sends the emails to the browser. Email invitations made through `devise` for users correctly run through Sendgrid but ALL other emails using `ActionMailer` continue to pop up in the browser no matter what I do.

I've tried everything I can think of. What am I missing please?

Or what can I do to debug what is [not] happening

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV['SMTP_HOST'] }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    user_name: 'apikey',
    password: 'whatever',
    address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    domain: 'blah.com',
    port: 587,
    authentication: :plain
  }
```

Comment: Restarted the app server after updating the development environment SMTP  configuration ?

Comment: What does "sends the emails to the browser" mean? Please be as specific as possible when explaining this because that statement does not make any sense. I don't think that this question can even be answered the way it's stated now.